# Custom delegate methods with multiple instances

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, multiple-instances

I've created a custom class, NetworkManager. It has two optional delegate methods. It works great, however, the issue is how to perform the delegate methods when there are multiple instances of `NetworkManager`. Here is a snippet of my code;

```
NetworkManager.h

@protocol NetworkManagerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
//call back for success message
-(void)handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *) jsonDictionary;

//call back for fail message
-(void)handleFailureMessageWitDictionary:(NSDictionary *) jsonDictionary;

@end
@interface NetworkManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<NetworkManagerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

And then in my view controller I have:

```
#pragma-mark NetowrkManager Delegate
-(void)handleFailureMessageWitDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary{

//failure


}

-(void)handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary{

//success

}
```

This works perfectly fine with one instance of `NetworkManager` but how to differentiate between two instances?

For example,

```
#pragma-mark NetowrkManager Delegate
-(void)handleFailureMessageWitDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary{

//if its networkManagerA do
// method A
//else if its networkManagerB do
//method B

-(void)handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary{

//if its networkManagerA do
// method A
//else if its networkManagerB do
//method B

}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you performing different actions depending on the instance? The point of a delegate is so that it can do a task and pass information to/from the delegate relatively universally.

Comment: @rebello95 If i have two difference Network calls to make I would like to use the same class, but based on the response perform a different action? Similar to how you can reference multiple UITableView instances in UITableView delegate.

Comment: shouldn't you be doing that in the delegate?

Comment: @rebello95 which delegate? My delegates above?

Comment: sorry I misread the last part of your question. Why don't you just add another parameter to the delegate method like `-(void)handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary manager:(id<NetworkManagerDelegate>)manager` then pass `self` from the network manager?

Comment: what info are included in jsonDictionary?  You can use info in that to distinguish which networkmanager instance made the call and act accordingly.

Comment: @rebello95 please post as an answer

Comment: @DevC just did. Note that in my above comment, `id<NetworkManagerDelegate>` should be `NetworkManager *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the instance back to your delegate, similar to the way `UITableView` delegation works:

```
-(void)handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary manager:(NetworkManager *)manager
```

Then, just pass `self` from the instance sending the callback:

```
[self handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:json manager:self];
```

Comment: passing `self` is giving me a warning. This is how I implement it in NetworkManager: `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:manager:)]) {
                                [self.delegate handleSuccessMessageWithDictionary:dataDict manager:self];
                            }` But I get this warning `Sending NetworkManager*const__strong to parameter of incompatible type id<NetworkManagerDelegate>`

Comment: @DevC please see my edit. You need to pass the instance of the manager, which doesn't conform to the delegate protocol.

Comment: I get an error now, `Expected Type`. Is it because `NetworkManager` is declared below the `@protocol` class. Sorry Im relatively new to the concept.

Comment: @DevC try putting `@class NetworkManager;` somewhere above the `@protocol` declaration in the delegate's file. Make sure to `#import NetworkManager.h` in the .m file as well

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to pass the instance of the *delegated* object back to the delegate; see the `UITableViewDelegate` methods such as:

```
- (BOOL)            tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

This way a single delegate object can work on multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but @rebello95 just got there before you (answered in the comments section). You have the correct answer also. :)

Answer (score 0):

While creating the object of  NetworkManager.h, set a property as to which class has created its object.In delegate method, check the property and perform your actions accordingly.
In NetworkManager.h create a property @property (nonatomic)  id className; and set this while creating object of NetworkManager.h : NETWORKManager.className = [self class];
Now in 
-(void)handleFailureMessageWitDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary{
if (_className == A){
...
}
else if (_className == B){
...
}
}